# .NET MVC script repeatedly used to delete SQL Server database preventing database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a site using ASP.NET MVC 4 using the Entity Framework 5. I have it hooked up to a SQL Server database. After finishing my project I decided to publish it and host it using Network Solutions. Network Solutions also hosts a SQL Server database that I try to connect to. When I try to access the site I the following error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I also am unable to log in to the database via SQL Server Management Studio

I contacted Network Solutions and their explanation was:

> "There has been a script repeatedly used to delete this database and we have recreated it again on your behalf."

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1754082
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295874
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout) +280
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +405
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClassa.<DbCreateDatabase>b__7(SqlConnection conn) +33
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +92
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +384
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +276
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext) +8
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create() +42
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +385
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__3() +19
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +164
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +185
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +27
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +58
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
JourneymensAid.Controllers.HomeController.FillSession(String email) in HomeController.cs:319
JourneymensAid.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs:28
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +56
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +256
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +22
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +87
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9630364
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Now for some relevant code snippets:

From my `MarketInitializer.cs` class:

```
public class MarketInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MarketContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MarketContext context)
```

The connection strings from my `web.config`:

```
<add name="MarketContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=<ip address of db>;Initial Catalog=<db name>;User Id=<user name> ;Password=<password>;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

After doing some research, I found out to remove the following line from `Global.asax.cs`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MarketContext>(new MarketInitializer());
```

I removed it and I still get the same error.  I've run google dry and I'm out of solutions.

What could possibly be deleting my database?

Answer (score 0):

If your database already exists, you can call `Database.SetInitializer<MarketContext>(null);`  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the migration script that is being applied or post it here. I bet there is something the seed is running that is deleting that database. Remember EF migrations contain just about everything you have changed in your models.

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

or

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: 0
```

will get you the migration script.